# Tip on modeling Cassandra database schema time querry

Tags: cassandra

I am working on modeling a database schema for Cassandra from existing relational schema, so in my database there are "events" (some events are scheduled events, some are recurring events) and in each "event" there are multiple "users" so relation is something as follows...
[image: relationship and fields of data]

In my cassandra database I currently have uuid of the event along with some other currently not relevant data as a **Partition key**, my clustering key is participant uuid, recurrence_rule is a static field, start_time is also a static field, status can be one of [NotStarted, Started, Ended], join password is a field in event_by_uuid database as well. So how do I make a table for supporting following querrys:

1. get all "upcoming events" for a certain **participant uuid** (events that have start_time in future in relation to start_time>now())
2. get all "past events" same as 1. but for start_time<now()
3. get all Started events for a certain participant

Also an issue I have is having this query based on time and having to insert any potential update to the event status to each and every one of those tables event_by_participant